# Fourier series and Riemann integral

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

On the heuristic level, one often says that given a periodic function with period L, its Fourier series converges when $L \rightarrow \infty$  towards a Riemann integral.

In other words, the intuition is that Fourier transforms can be viewed as a limit of
Fourier series as the period grows to infinity, and the sum becomes an
integral.

My question is: how can this be made precise? What kind of convergence under which assumptions can one expect?

Comment: I believe this is made precise in Stein and Shakarchi's book on Fourier Analysis. http://books.google.ca/books?id=FAOc24bTfGkC&pg=PA158&dq=%22The+mathematical+thrust+of+the+principle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Esa7T5PZIsqriQKluNjPDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22The%20mathematical%20thrust%20of%20the%20principle%22&f=false

Comment: I suppose you mean "Fourier transform" when you say "Riemann integral"?

Comment: yes, this is what I meant with the second "paragraph"